# How do I make my application start at the bottom right?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm working on this application that has a fairly small UI. 315 x 340.
And when I minimize it, it prompts the user with a BalloonTip at the bottom right from the taskbar..

When I click the notifyIcon at the taskbar I want the application to open at the bottom right of the screen, no matter what Screen Resolution im on.
I would assume this is based upon the project settings and not code related.

How do I make the application start at the bottom right of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `StartPosition` of your form to `Manual`. You can then use the `Screen` object to get the working area (which is different from the resolution due to the task bar, app bars etc), and set your position accordingly, for example

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  int x;
  int y;
  Screen screen;

  base.OnLoad(e);

  screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
  x = screen.WorkingArea.Right - this.Width;
  y = screen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height;

  this.Location = new Point(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether Windows Forms or WPF:

[WinForms: Setting the Screen Location of a Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984420(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    Rectangle area = Screens.Primary.WorkingArea;
    Location = new Point(area.Width-315, area.Height-340);
}
```

In WPF this is quite similar.

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
    Rectangle area = Screens.Primary.WorkingArea;
    Left = area.Width-315;
    Top = area.Height-340;
}
```